# How can i remove "Sections" from url by url writing?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am working on vb.net application and i need to remove word "sections" from the url.

url: http://www.examplewebsite.com/sections/page.aspx

This is what i need to do by regular expression in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rewrite rule in your web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hide sections">
      <match url="^(.+)$
      <action type="Rewrite" url="sections/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any module required to have on server for this to work because it is not working for me? Also if you could let me know the section where i need to put this code?

Comment: Yes, you need the URL Rewrite module to make this work - http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

There is a video on this webpage to show how it works.

You can use the tool to create the URL rewrite rules. Just add the urls in my code in the URL rewrite module accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, we can't have that module. So can't test the your solution. But many thanks for your time.